# How to delete Excel cells when running a macro from VBs Script

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have a VBS script which runs a VBA macro in Excel. The macro works when I manually run it in the Excel file, but when called from the VBS it won't delete out the existing data before running the queries.

Here is my VBS script dealing with Excel:

```
Dim xlApp, xlBook
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("Y:\Public\Eoin\Complaints Report\Complaints Report.xlsm", False)

msgbox("3")

xlApp.Run "Complaints_Report.Complaints_Report()"

WScript.Sleep 100000
xlbook.Save
xlBook.Close False
set xlBook = Nothing

xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Here is my Excel VBA macro stored in a module:

```
Sub Complaints_Report()
    Sheets("Complaints Report").Activate
    'Clear out old detail
    Range("A2:Z10000").Clear

    'Declare variables'
    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

    'Open Connection'
    objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
            "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
            "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=***)" & _
            "(HOST=*****)(PORT=****))" & _
            "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME =*****))); uid=******; pwd=*****;"
    objMyConn.Open

    'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
    strSQL = "Select distinct * From Temp_Final_Complaints_Report"

    'Open Recordset'
    Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
    objMyRecordset.Open strSQL

    'Copy Data to Excel'
    Sheets("Complaints Report").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
End Sub
```

The macro returns the results but does not delete out everything in the sheet beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. The `Run` method needs the name of the `Sub` to run, so there should not be parentheses:

   Change:

   ```
   xlApp.Run "Complaints_Report.Complaints_Report()"
   ```

   To:

   ```
   xlApp.Run "Complaints_Report.Complaints_Report"
   ```
2. Make sure to specify the sheet explicitly when using `Range`, as the activation of the sheet may not be reliable

   Change:

   ```
   Range("A2:Z10000").Clear
   ```

   To:

   ```
   Sheets("Complaints Report").Range("A2:Z10000").Clear
   ```

You may then even remove the statement to activate the sheet, as the code will do its job without that.

Comment: That's still not doing it. Currently in my excel file I have data in rows 2:13 and I inputted some dummy data in cells in A21 and A33 to make sure the macro will catch any time there is a blank row. Currently, the macro will run the SQL queries and output them bu the dummy data remains.

Comment: Even commenting out everything bar                                   Sheets("Complaints Report").Activate
    'Clear out old detail
     Sheets("Complaints Report").Range("A2:Z10000").Clear                           does nothing

Comment: Just spotted another issue when trying to mimic your set-up: the parentheses in the VBScript should be left out. See my updated answer.